# Is there a way to get information on my closed and deleted questions and answers?

Tags: support, close-reasons, deleted-answers, closed-questions, deleted-questions

Is there a way to find a complete list of:

1. Questions and answers of mine that were closed and deleted.
2. The Politics SE users and/or moderators who voted to close or delete the questions or answers.
3. The reasons cited for voting to close or delete the questions or answers.

Comment: You can find most of the information you are looking for in [your profile](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/21216). For deleted posts, look for the "deleted recent" links at the bottom of your [questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/21216?tab=questions) and [answers](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/21216?tab=answers) lists. Moderators have access to older deleted posts that may not appear on those lists. If you require access to these posts as well, please update your question to explain why that is.

Comment: @yannis Yes, the question asks for the complete list of closed and deleted questions and answers, including older questions and and answers not listed in the profile that moderators have access to.

Comment: @yannis Why are you requesting "why" for the support request? What difference does a "why" make as to a moderator answering the question by providing all of the requested data in a single answer? _"user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required."_ [Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 United States (CC BY-SA 3.0 US)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/)

Comment: @guest271314 The license you granted stack exchange pertains to the terms under which they are allowed to display your content. Moderators being conditionally willing to provide links to deleted answers is really just a favor and not really something required by the license. I suspect they're asking because they're not convinced you're going to use this data for responsible conduct.

Comment: @guest271314 Like haranguing users that voted to delete, or try & call them out. User conduct is focused on content on Stack exchange, calling out specific users personally is pretty much off limits. Calling out behavior and actions, like answers being deleted, is fine and often done on meta or via private contact to the mods as part of the community moderation process (the process generally includes community review of community actions, and as a part of the community you have the opportunity to start that process), but people often want this information to somehow contact the voting users

Comment: which is not really how challenging moderation decisions is done usually.

Comment: @Magisch "calling out" is not possible. The users already publicly made the vote. They called themselves out. The question simply asks to post the complete list of those public activities.

Comment: @guest271314 eh. Yes and no. Yes as in the votes are fair game for discussion, no as in you don't really need to know who voted to have that discussion. There's a reason the software limits who can see who delete votes and who didn't, and more reason why the software won't tell people who flagged their posts.

Comment: @Magisch The question is in response to this comment by a moderator _"If you wish to discuss a pattern of actions against your posts, then a single meta question would do."_ https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/how-can-we-improve-a-question-closed-as-partisan#comment9121_3761. Not sure why the request is problematic. When the question is placed on hold or closed, or deleted answer the votes are publicly viewable. There is no malicious intent associated with the request. Ironically, by not answering the question suspicion is aroused for not answering the question.

Comment: @guest271314 but delete voters are not public, they're very restricted in who can view them. Namely 10+ users and the post owner only. Even the fact that no convenient listing is available for the post owner themselves is deliberate. You're not supposed to go after the users voting on your posts under normal circumstances. In any case, a mod may grant your request possibly, but I wanted to explain why they might ask for a reason. This is just informed speculation based on what I know about SE sites.

Comment: @Magisch Delete votes are public.  Vote to close votes are also public. Can post screenshots of closed question and deleted answers with users names attached to prove that fact.

Comment: @guest271314 they're not. Even with the direct link to one of the recent deleted answers here (https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37875/why-is-a-border-wall-such-a-polarising-issue-in-american-politics/37921#37921) neither me nor any other sub 10k user is allowed to see who voted to delete. Seeing who voted to delete is a high bar of privilege and that information is restricted from the vast majority of the site's users.

Comment: @Magisch That is simply not true. _"deleted by Martin Tournoij, Alexei, bytebuster Jan 11 at 13:14"_ https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/37859/21216; _"deleted by gerrit, tim, Jeff Lambert yesterday"_ https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/37921/21216

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88418/discussion-between-magisch-and-guest271314).

Comment: @Magisch you can actually see deleted questions once you [reach 2k rep](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) because the site is still in beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all your closed questions [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+user%3Ame). Alternatively, you can search on the main site for `closed:yes`

#### Deleted posts (10K+ users only)

You can find all your deleted posts [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3Ayes). Alternatively, you can search on the main site for `deleted:yes`.

Note that:

> only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content

Comment: I'll just point out that the operator `deleted:1` only works for 10k+ users on graduated sites, 2k+ users on beta sites. See [help on searching](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/searching) or [help on privileges](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). This threshold is also mentioned in the post on [meta.se] which lead to introducing this feature: [Enable searching with deleted:1 for 10k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145060).

Comment: @Martin doesn't it work for users trying to find their own posts?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not work for low rep users. I left a bit more detailed response [in the main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6619/conversation/search-using-deleted1).

Answer (score 10):

A desire for revenge [is not tolerated](https://politics.stackexchange.com/conduct) on this site, @guest271314. Instead of focusing oneself on hurting other users who voted to close posts, one should see if these posts can be improved.

Other than this, *Use the Force, Luke*:

A simple **Stack Exchange API** [query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&closed=True&user=21216&filter=!.FdEuFCavhWn(SFXp.E7aY05Ek70J&site=politics&run=true) returns a list of Closed Questions originated by a certain User. Further playing with the Filters may be necessary.

Comment: The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is a good alternative to the API, especially for people who feel comfortable with SQL.

Comment: @bytebuster Where does the question include the language "revenge" and "hurting others"?

Comment: The API portion of this answer is useful, but the unsubstantiated imputation of malice is not.